# Allure report getting NaN% when integrated with cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, allure

I am using allure reporting in my cypress , but after the execution I could see only the allure report folder getting generated but the allure results folder is not generated.

Configuration made in my code as below:

**plugins/index.js**

```
/// <reference types="@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin" />


const allureWriter = require("@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer");

module.exports = (on, config) => {
allureWriter(on, config);
return config;
};
```

**support/index.js**

```
import '@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin';
```

**in package.json**

```
"allure:report": "allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report",
"allure:clear_results":"(if exist allure-results (rmdir /S /Q allure-results))",
"allure:clear_report":"  (if exist allure-report (rmdir  /S /Q allure-report))",
"precy-run": "yarn run allure:clear_results && yarn run allure:clear_report",
"cy-run": "cypress run --env allure=true",
"postcy-run": "yarn run allure:report",
```

**output in terminal**

```
$ allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report
allure-results does not exist
 Report successfully generated to allure-report
```

I tried viewing the report in live server in VS code

[image]

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem ?

Comment: Nothing immediately pops up as wrong,  assuming you don't ever want to see TRENDS. Assuming this is the order you are running the commands in: 
`npm run precy-run`,`npm run cy-run`,`npm run postcy-run` by that time you should have the `/allure-report` generated so no need to rerun, just use the live server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me, just I placed the result path in the root, looks like allure report look for the result in the root file if you change it, it doesn't work

```
"env": { 
    "allureResultsPath": "allure-results",
  },
```

Comment: This works. Weird since this is the default value, but works.

Comment: which file to add? can you help guys ? I've added in cypress.config.js but it didn't work.

Comment: there is an issue with latest versions of cypress and allure. that might be the cause 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/27113
so my question is redundant right now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add "`--env allure=true --reporter mocha-allure-reporter`" while working with Allure Report integration with Cypress.

My script in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "cypress:run:loginModule": "npx cypress run --browser chrome --headless --spec 'cypress/integration/Auth/*.js' **--env allure=true --reporter mocha-allure-reporter",
  "report:login:allure": "allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report && allure open allure-report",
  "test-loginModule:allure": "npm run cypress:run:loginModule && npm run report:login:allure"
}
```

It works for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

From the output

> allure-results does not exist

refers to the folder named "allure-results".

The clean-up script removes the folder with `rmdir` but does not recreate it.

```js
"allure:clear_results":"(if exist allure-results (rmdir /S /Q allure-results))",
```

Change the script to

```js
"allure:clear_results":"(if exist allure-results (rmdir /S /Q allure-results && mkdir allure-results))",
```